# lua popen() console output in html

Tags: lua

I'm having problem with simple script:

```
<%- 
local f = io.popen("/sbin/mtd wl0 constatus") -- runs command
local l = f:read("*a") -- read output of command
print(l)
f:close()
-%>
```

It executes command and prints output in html file. Problem is that output should be like this:

```
Connection Status
=============================
Noise Level      -256 dBm
Channel Load        1 %
Disconnections        0

 MAC address       | RSSI dBm       | PHY Rate Mb/s | Type   | Tx packets  | Tx dropped  | Rx packets
```

But by default is in one line, without rows, using `<textarea>` I've achieved desired output format but `<textarea>` rows should be dynamic in my needs (new row = new connected device)but unfortunately isn't.

How to format console output as it shows on console or in textarea with dynamic rows/height ?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert `'\n'`s to `<br>`s for proper rendering text lines inside html?  Using `string.gsub` of course.  You can surround your text with `<pre>` tag as the second solution.